# Skip action when DictReader key value matches previous key value

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, opencsv

When I'm opening a csv to get data, I'm trying to parse when I have a duplicate iteration of the same key pairs.

Snap of CSV: [DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tczJN.png)

```
cards = []
import csv
with open('ip_list.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        cards.append(
            f'We will send the {row["last"]}s a Christmas Card in {row["state"]} '
        )
        print(row)
print('\n')
print('\n'.join(cards))
```

RESULTS:

```
OrderedDict([('first', 'Monica'), ('last', 'Parker'), ('state', 'Florida')])
OrderedDict([('first', 'Bill'), ('last', 'Parker'), ('state', 'Florida')])
OrderedDict([('first', 'Bob'), ('last', 'Smith'), ('state', 'Texas')])
OrderedDict([('first', 'Bob'), ('last', 'Clark'), ('state', 'Texas')])

We will send the Parkers a Christmas Card in Florida 
**We will send the Parkers a Christmas Card in Florida** 
We will send the Smiths a Christmas Card in Texas 
We will send the Clarks a Christmas Card in Texas
```

In this example, Monica and Bill Parker live at the same address, so we only need to send this card once.  I want the code to see that keys 'last' and 'state' match previous line and skip the 2nd instance but continue to perform the 3rd and 4th. I expect this could happen for several kids in the same household too so maybe we catch first instance and drop the rest?

Comment: You probably should store every sent card relevant attributes in a `sent_card` list and check the list before you send a new one. Unless you assume kids from the same household are always in adjacent lines.

Comment: It may not be always true but the data will be sorted by last name so they "should" always be the next line(s).